How is information defined when considering locality in quantum mechanics?
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
My question is a follow-up from this discussion about the presence of non-local correlations in a theory that is deemed local. The first answer talks about the inability to use entaglement for superluminal communication between oberservers. This explanation also came up in an answer to another question that is closely related to mine. I had to prove this concept as part of my curriculum and understood the idea with the help of a specific example. The argument could be condensed as follows:
Two observers, Alice and Bob, are allowed to decide the bases in which they would conduct measurements before they and their respective qubits are separated in space by some arbitrary amount. For the sake of generality, we assumed that Bob chose a basis expressed as $\vec{n}(\theta, \phi).\vec{\sigma}$ in the matrix form (I am denoting the corresponding basis vectors as $\ket{\theta, \phi}^+$ and $\ket{\theta, \phi}^-$). In this particular example, they had a $\ket{\Phi^+}$ bell state as the shared qudit. The exercise was to find out if Alice could choose a basis such that Bob's qubit would always be in one of his basis states after her measurement. It was found possible, if Alice performed her measurements in the $\vec{n}(\theta, -\phi).\vec{\sigma}$ basis (basis vectors: $\ket{\theta, -\phi}^+$ and $\ket{\theta, -\phi}^-$). However, for any measurement performed by Alice, the probability that Bob would obtain $\ket{\theta, \phi}^+$ or $\ket{\theta, \phi}^-$ after his measurement would always be half and half. This implied that there is no measurement that Alice could perform to make Bob's measurement results 'meaningful' (contain any non-trivial information).
Through this example, I understand why information in the form of bits or bit strings could not be communicated instantaneously using entanglement. However, the information about the occurance of a measurement still seems to be happening instantaneously. In other words, considering the Copenhagen interpretation, the information that Bob's qubit needs to 'collapse' after Alice's measurement still seems to be getting transferred instantaneously. My notion of locality is that it should be related more to the fundamental information about the occurance of events (measurements in this case) than to the information contained in bit strings.
Parallelly, one could argue that the 'collapse' itself should not be treated within the framework of physics, since the two superposed states represent two alternate realities. Would this idea be reminiscent of the many-worlds interpretation? If we were to resort to that interpretation, it could actually resolve this issue because, according to my (probably naive) understanding, we could say that "the correlations kind of always existed retrocausally" after diverging into a particular 'branch' formed by a measurement. There would be no reason to appeal to hidden variables or non-locality to explain the correlations in that case. Does this not make the Copenhangen and many world interpretations distinguishable? And does it not give more credibility to the latter? Also, as a slightly tangential question, is retrocausality always associated with the many-worlds interpretation, or could it also be compatible with other interpretations?

On your final tangential question:  in quantum foundations, Retrocausality and Many-Worlds are usually considered diametrically opposed (except perhaps by Lev Vaidman).  The former is trying to make sense of quantum phenomena as being explained by events in ordinary space and time, while the latter tries to explain things in some enormous Hilbert space.  I guess if you try to pick out and analyze one particular "world", it might look retrocausal, but Many-Worlds proponents like Sean Carroll would say this is a mistake and a mis-reading of the Everettian framework.


Through this example, I understand why information in the form of bits or bit strings could not be communicated instantaneously using entanglement. However, the information about the occurance of a measurement still seems to be happening instantaneously. In other words, considering the Copenhagen interpretation, the information that Bob's qubit needs to 'collapse' after Alice's measurement still seems to be getting transferred instantaneously. My notion of locality is that it should be related more to the fundamental information about the occurance of events (measurements in this case) than to the information contained in bit strings.

Theories that have a single outcome and agree with experimentally tested implications of quantum theory are not local nor are they Lorentz invariant
https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04966

Parallelly, one could argue that the 'collapse' itself should not be treated within the framework of physics, since the two superposed states represent two alternate realities. Would this idea be reminiscent of the many-worlds interpretation? If we were to resort to that interpretation, it could actually resolve this issue because, according to my (probably naive) understanding, we could say that "the correlations kind of always existed retrocausally" after diverging into a particular 'branch' formed by a measurement. There would be no reason to appeal to hidden variables or non-locality to explain the correlations in that case. Does this not make the Copenhangen and many world interpretations distinguishable? And does it not give more credibility to the latter? Also, as a slightly tangential question, is retrocausality always associated with the many-worlds interpretation, or could it also be compatible with other interpretations?

Lev Vaidman has written about backwards evolving quantum states in the many worlds interpretation (MWI) but I haven't seen any account of whether he thinks this would explain Bell correlations:
https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4396/
There is an explanation of Bell correlations in the MWI. In the Heisenberg picture of quantum theory the evolution of the observables of a system is only affected by local interactions. Each observable carries information about the observables of the other systems it has interacted with that can't be accessed by measurements on that system alone: locally inaccessible quantum information. This information doesn't change the expectation values of any measurements so it is immune to decoherence and can be carried in decoherent channels such as electronic signals in a computer carrying information about a measurement result or whatever. The correlations between the measurement results are only established when the results are compared and so the correlations arise entirely locally:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
Since this explanation of how Bell correlations are established relies on applying quantum theory to macroscopic objects it can't work in any other interpretation of quantum theory. This makes the MWI and Copenhagen distinguishable in terms of how they explain Bell correlations.
However, the Copenhagen interpretation (CI) is sufficiently vague about what is happening in reality that this doesn't give a clear experimental contradiction between the CI and unmodified quantum theory. To the best of my knowledge the only experiment that has been proposed to test the Copenhagen interpretation was proposed by David Deutsch in Section 7 of this paper:
https://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Deutsch.pdf
It should be noted that Deutsch regards the content in this paper about the preferred basis as wrong. He is satisfied that the correct set of observables for dividing the multiverse into worlds is provided by decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
